# Echo выдает ошибку?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 echo "    
<table>
<tr>
         <td><a href='page.php?id=<?=$myrow4[id]';?>><img alt='аватар' src='<?=$avatar;?>'></a></td>

         <td>Автор:    <a href='page.php?id=<?=$myrow4[id]';?>><?=$author;?></a><br>
          Дата:    <?=$messages['date'];?><br>
                         Сообщение:<br>

                     <?=$messages['text'];?><br>

         </td>  
         </tr>
</table>";
```

Что здесь не так скажите пожалуйста? выдает ошибку синтаксиса(

Comment: замените echo на <?php ?>

Comment: нет это только кусок кода пусть вас не вводит в заблуждение то что я не экранировал скрипт <?php ?> в документе это есть..

Comment: @DanteLoL, а зачем Вы делаете php-вставки, например, <?=$myrow4[id]';?>. Это первое, что бросается в глаза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

```
?>
<table>
<tr>
         <td><a href='page.php?id=<?=$myrow4['id'];?>'><img alt='аватар' src='<?=$avatar;?>'></a></td>

         <td>Автор:    <a href='page.php?id=<?=$myrow4['id'];?>'><?=$author;?></a><br>
          Дата:    <?=$messages['date'];?><br>
                         Сообщение:<br>

                     <?=$messages['text'];?><br>

         </td>  
         </tr>
</table>;
<?php
```

---

```
echo "    
<table>
<tr>
         <td><a href='page.php?id={$myrow4['id']}'><img alt='аватар' src='$avatar'></a></td>

         <td>Автор:    <a href='page.php?id={$myrow4['id']}'>$author</a><br>
          Дата:    {$messages['date']}<br>
                         Сообщение:<br>

                     {$messages['text']}<br>

         </td>  
         </tr>
</table>";
```

а ваш код это что-то странное.

Comment: Бинго) 2й)

Comment: ммм помогло топомогло но ширина таблицы не фиксируется все равно ее содерживое ее растаракнивает\ как можно ширину зафиксировать посоветуете??